# DevExpress XtraGrid - Cannot select Master Row

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a gridView with a 1to1 master-detail relationship for each master row. When a user clicks on the **detail** view I want to make sure that the master row is also activated (has the activated icon in the very left column):

[image]

This works fine if I navigate the master and detail grids with the keyboard, but doesn't work with the mouse. So I wrote to following code to try and fix this, but it doesn't work. This code is triggered via the detail view's click event:

```
GridView focusedView = gridView3.GridControl.FocusedView as GridView;

// get the currently selected row in the child view
int focusedRowHandle = focusedView.FocusedRowHandle;

// get the parentView's row handle that owns the child view
int sourceRowHandle = focusedView.SourceRowHandle;

GridView parentView = focusedView.ParentView as GridView;
parentView.BeginSelection();
parentView.SelectRow(sourceRowHandle);
parentView.EndSelection();
```

Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Single Row selection mode? If multiple selection is disabled (the `ColumnViewOptionsSelection.MultiSelect` option is set to `false`) the [SelectRow](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_SelectRowtopic) method **does nothing**.

Use the [ColumnView.FocusedRowHandle](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_FocusedRowHandletopic) property to select the master row that owns the detail View.

Related article: [Selection Overview](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument711)

Comment: SelectRow **seems** to work, but it is always selecting the first row of the all of the master rows. Not sure if it is because I am using the above logic during the click event on a row.